# Visual Studio 2013 Community Problems

Tags: windows, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Im tearing my hair out with this one Im afraid and am down hours and hours.

Firstly I wanted to install VS Community to use with Unity. Im running windows 8.1 pro.

But I had trouble installing. Long story short there were some fonts in windows\fonts that the VS installer didnt like. So I moved the fonts and the installer ran through successfully. I then installed the VS 2013 Tools for Unity.

So then I imported the Unity VS tools to my project. Now my unity project hangs when unity opens. I fixed unity by removing the Unity VS stuff form the project directory.

I started getting errors on screen that said "An unhandled exception System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException) occurred in ZAPrivacyService.exe[3168]

The Just In Time Debugger was launched without necessary security permissions etc etc

Also the above error message appears very frequently and even if i ignore the dialogue it just keeps popping up every minute or so. I just off the JIT prompts but then I get an error message saying that no JIT is available. instead of the other error message. ZAPrivacyService seems to be part of ZoneAlarm. So I downloaded and reinstalled it. No joy. I tried uninstalling the Unity VS tools. I then went to Programs and Features to remove VS. However when I click on VS I only get the option to change. So I click change and the VS splash screen briefly appears. Then nothing. I also tried rerunning the VS installer(from the ISO and the web exe) and the same thing happens.

I do want to get VS running I thought a reinstall could fix it. But not to even be able to reinstall.....
Also how can I set Vs to ignore everything except the projects im working on IN VS?

Any ideas????

Thanks